# rotation in landscape and presentModalViewController do, it has space on right side

Tags: iphone, ipad, rotation, landscape, portrait

I am upgrading my application that has new feature that supports landscape mode.

but i have little problem that is the following video.

[the is video you can see the problem.](http://clipitto.com/hgfLOu)

I don't know What's the problem.

Help me :)

Comment: I think you need to set trailing constraints on your view from storyboard. So that it can re-layout on orientation change.

Comment: @AshishP. Thanks for reply. I solved this problem that just changed size as freeform on XIB file.